# java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

im currently getting this error when i run my programs query,

> java.sql.SQLException: Column count
>   doesn't match value count at row 1

but i dont know why , all my values are there and match up.
this is the code were i do my sql statement.

```
c = DriverManager.getConnection( url, username, password );


String selectStatement = "INSERT INTO entry ( id, name, title, note) VALUES (?),(?),(?),(?)";
PreparedStatement prepStmt = (PreparedStatement) c.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
prepStmt.setInt(1, idSeed++);
prepStmt.setString(2, name2);
prepStmt.setString(3, title2);
prepStmt.setString(4, note2);
prepStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Values tag should be like VALUES (?,?,?,?);

Comment: are you getting correct output ? i have doubt in it. i mean other changes need rather than insert query.

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect. It must be

```
INSERT INTO entry ( id, name, title, note) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 0):

please do the following changes in your existence code,

> maintain idSeed's value too.

```
String selectStatement = "INSERT INTO entry ( id, name, title, note) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement prepStmt = (PreparedStatement) c.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
prepStmt.setInt(1, idSeed); // remove ++ from here, do it in last
prepStmt.setString(2, name2);
prepStmt.setString(3, title2);
prepStmt.setString(4, note2);
prepStmt.executeUpdate();

Notes entry = new Notes(idSeed, name2, title2,note2 ); //now you will get exactly what inserted into DB table
entries.add(entry);

idSeed++; // now increment it, which will reflect into next iteration...
```